# What causes the -2147352571 type mismatch error in VBA userform?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Currently I'm working on a Access-Excel connection with an userform. Within this userform data needs to be exported from Excel to Access. The following error occurs (vba error --2147352571 type mismatch) and i can't find where the problem is in my code assigned to the export button. This is my code:

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection 'dim the ADO collection class
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset 'dim the ADO recordset class
Dim dbPath
Dim x As Long, i As Long
'Error handler
On Error GoTo errHandler:

dbPath = ActiveSheet.Range("I9").Value

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection ' Initialise the collection class variable

'Connection class is equipped with a —method— named Open
'—-4 aguments—- ConnectionString, UserID, Password, Options
'ConnectionString formula—-Key1=Value1;Key2=Value2;Key_n=Value_n;
 cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath

'ADO library is equipped with a class named Recordset
 Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset

'ConnectionString Open '—-5 aguments—-
'Source, ActiveConnection, CursorType, LockType, Options
 rst.Open Source:="TAGInformation", ActiveConnection:=cnn, _
 CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
 Options:=adCmdTable

 'send the data
   rst.AddNew
   For i = 1 To 213
   rst(Cells(1, i).Value) = Me.Controls("Arec" & i).Value
   Next i
   rst.Update

 'update for the next ID
 Sheet1.Range("K9").Value = Arec1.Value + 1

 'clear the userform values
 For x = 1 To 213
 Me.Controls("Arec" & x).Value = ""
 Next

 'add the next user ID
 Me.Arec1 = Sheet1.Range("K9").Value
 ' Close the connection
 rst.Close
 cnn.Close
 Set rst = Nothing
 Set cnn = Nothing

 'commuinicate with the user
 MsgBox " The data has been successfully sent to the access database"
 On Error GoTo 0
 Exit Sub
 errHandler:
 Set rst = Nothing
 Set cnn = Nothing
 MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure 
 cmdAdd"
 End Sub
```

Comment: Which line of code is causing the error?

Comment: I don't see any validation of the values you're setting fields to at all. It could be any of the *213 fields* in your table, so without knowing the schema of the table and the data you're trying to import, this is likely unanswerable.

Comment: I'm not sure where to find this, when i use the debugging function this code is skipped automatically..

Comment: Use Parameters for your values, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/append-and-createparameter-methods-example-vb?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @comintern would it help to add all fields like this instead of the loop?:    '.AddNew
'.Fields("Id").Value = Arec1
'.Fields("Surname").Value = Arec2
'.Fields("FirstName").Value = Arec3
'.Fields("Address").Value = Arec4
'.Fields("Phone").Value = Arec5
' .Fields("Mobile").Value = Arec6
'.Fields("Email").Value = Arec7
'.Update
'End With

Comment: Turn off your error handler temporarily to see where the error pops up. E.g. comment this out `On Error GoTo errHandler:`

Comment: @ryanwildry my error occurs in the following line:    rst(Cells(1, i).Value) = Me.Controls("Arec" & i).Value

Comment: It's a type error. You need to define the types for each field, take a look at the link I shared in my earlier comment.

Comment: The method you use to add the fields doesn't matter - what matters is that one of them doesn't match the expected type. The only way you're going to find it is by stepping through it with a debugger, comparing each value to your schema, and catching the one with the wrong data type.  Nobody here can do that, because we don't know the schema, and we don't know the data you're trying to put into that schema.

Comment: @RyanWildry first of all thanks for your reply, so what I need to do is: -Open command object with one parameter; -Get parameter value and append parameter;- Create recordset by executing the command. After doing this, with the steps from the link you have sent me, it should work?

Comment: @BramAgterberg, yes exactly. You want to ensure the types match. If you want a helper function to make it easy, try this -- > https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/46346/108307

Comment: @RyanWildry I can't get it working, is there any way how you can help me?  The Select  TypeName is not doing anything

Comment: @BramAgterberg I'll post an answer with an approach that might help later tonight.

Comment: @RyanWildry thanks in advance, it would help me a lot!

Comment: @RyanWildry I'm currently doing it like this: 
    rst.AddNew
    rst.Fields("Id").value = Arec1
    rst.Fields("G-TAGName").value = Arec2
    rst.Fields("G-EquipmentType").value = Arec3
    rst.Fields("G-EquipmentFamily").value = Arec4
'etc..

    rst.Fields("O-Density (kg/m3)").value = Arec18
    rst.Update

The error no occurs at Arec18, which is an number type in my Acces DB. Which is strange, because the first field is also an number type an works fine..

When I know how to change the fieldtypes in here i can manually state all the fields instead of looping it, i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments here is an approach that I hope at least gets you closer to your end goal.

A bit of background on my setup, as this code won't necessarily be a drop in and it works.

I have a table in an Access file, with the following schema.

```html
+---------------+--------------+
| FieldName     | FieldType    |
+---------------+--------------+
| DateField     | Date         |
+---------------+--------------+
| TextField     | ShortText    |
+---------------+--------------+
| LongIntField  | Long Integer |
+---------------+--------------+
| DoubleField   | Double       |
+---------------+--------------+
| IntField      | Integer      |
+---------------+--------------+
| CurrencyField | Currency     |
+---------------+--------------+
| LongTextField | LongText     |
+---------------+--------------+
| ByteField     | Byte         |
+---------------+--------------+
| DecimalField  | Decimal      |
+---------------+--------------+
| YesNoField    | Boolean      |
+---------------+--------------+
```

I have a row to insert on Sheet1 of Excel. My headers are on Row 1, with the values on Row 2. I use the `FieldName` to locate the `Field` in the `Fields` Collection to be able to determine the type and get the appropriate value needed to add to the database.

Here is the code:

---

```
Private ErrorCollection As Collection

'Probably overkill, but I found added all the ADO Field Types
Public Enum ADOFieldTypes
    adArray = 8192
    adBigInt = 20
    adBinary = 128
    adBoolean = 11
    adBSTR = 8
    adChapter = 136
    adChar = 129
    adCurrency = 6
    adDate = 7
    adDBDate = 133
    adDBTime = 134
    adDBTimeStamp = 135
    adDecimal = 14
    adDouble = 5
    adEmpty = 0
    adError = 10
    adFileTime = 64
    adGUID = 72
    adIDispatch = 9
    adInteger = 3
    adIUnknown = 13
    adLongVarBinary = 205
    adLongVarChar = 201
    adLongVarWChar = 203
    adNumeric = 131
    adPropVariant = 138
    adSingle = 4
    adSmallInt = 2
    adTinyInt = 16
    adUnsignedBigInt = 21
    adUnsignedInt = 19
    adUnsignedSmallInt = 18
    adUnsignedTinyInt = 17
    adUserDefined = 132
    adVarBinary = 204
    adVarChar = 200
    adVariant = 12
    adVarNumeric = 139
    adVarWChar = 202
    adWChar = 130
End Enum

Public Sub DBExample()
    Const ConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=YOURPATHGOESHERE"
    Const SQL As String = "Select * from [Example] where id = 1" ' Simple query that returns all fields for the insert
    Set ErrorCollection = New Collection

    Dim conn            As ADODB.connection: Set conn = New ADODB.connection
    Dim rst             As ADODB.Recordset: Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ws              As Excel.Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim i               As Long
    Dim Fields          As ADODB.Fields
    Dim FieldName       As String
    Dim FieldValue      As Variant
    Dim FieldType       As Long
    Dim ErrorString     As String
    Dim ErrorItem       As Variant

    conn.Open ConnectionString
    rst.Open SQL, conn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic
    Set Fields = rst.Fields 'Get all the fields for the Database Table

    rst.AddNew
    For i = 1 To 10
        FieldName = ws.Cells(1, i).Value2 'Get the FieldName
        FieldType = rst.Fields(ws.Cells(1, i).Value2).Type 'Get the Field's Type from ADODB
        FieldValue = ws.Cells(2, i).Value2 'Get the value to update
        rst.Fields(FieldName).Value = getFieldValue(FieldType, FieldValue, FieldName) 'Assign the value
    Next

    'If, and only if there are no errors, update the DB
    If ErrorCollection.Count = 0 Then
        rst.Update
    Else
        'Print out error descriptions, which fields are still having issues?
        For Each ErrorItem In ErrorCollection
            ErrorString = ErrorItem & vbNewLine & ErrorString
        Next

        Debug.Print ErrorString
    End If

    conn.close
End Sub

'This maps the field type, and coverts the Excel value to that type
'I've only included the types I thought were most relevant for MS Access
'My Database has the following Type in a table: Date, ShortText, Long, Double, Integer, Decimal, Byte, Boolean (Yes/No), Currency, LongText
Private Function getFieldValue(FieldType As ADOFieldTypes, FieldValue As Variant, FieldName As String) As Variant
On Error GoTo errorHandler:

    Select Case FieldType
        Case adDate
            getFieldValue = CDate(FieldValue)
        Case adVarWChar
            getFieldValue = FieldValue
        Case adInteger
            getFieldValue = CLng(FieldValue)
        Case adDouble
            getFieldValue = CDbl(FieldValue)
        Case adSmallInt
            getFieldValue = CInt(FieldValue)
        Case adCurrency
             getFieldValue = CCur(FieldValue)
        Case adLongVarWChar
            getFieldValue = FieldValue
        Case adUnsignedTinyInt
            getFieldValue = CByte(FieldValue)
        Case adNumeric
            getFieldValue = CDec(FieldValue)
        Case adBoolean
            getFieldValue = CBool(FieldValue)
    End Select

    Exit Function

errorHandler:
    'This will return the FieldType Enum value, you can reference the number returned to ADOFieldTypes
    ErrorCollection.Add "Could not add " & FieldName & " with value: " & FieldValue & " it has a type of " & FieldType
End Function
```

Comment: I applied your code to my context, it seems to have solved the type error. When i try to run my userform i get an ''error 3265 item not found in this collection''. The error occurs in the following line of code:

rst(Cells(1, L).value) = Me.Controls("Arec" & L).value 

Which is part of the following loop:

'send the data
    rst.AddNew
    For L = 1 To 211
    rst(Cells(1, L).value) = Me.Controls("Arec" & L).value
    Next L
    rst.Update

Comment: Well that's progress. This error is new, it means the field name doesn't match the field name in the database. Check your database to ensure each field name or index exists in the database. You can print out the field names in the `Fields` to see what's up. At this point it is starting to sound like a new question, if you are still having trouble I'd recommend creating a new question for this one.

Comment: thanks for your help! It's starting to come together with declaring the Arec(textboxes) and defining them as ArecInt, ArecText etc. When I needed I'll post a new question.

Comment: Glad it helped, if this helped resolve your original question. Please consider marking as the accepted answer.